# SAP GUI Scripting Error 619 control could not be found by id

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm working on a project of automatizing the extraction of a report/info from SAP using SAP GUI Scripting tool and VBA, and I'm getting this error:

> Se ha producido el error '619' en tiempo de ejecución:
>
> The control cound not be found by id.

At this line, that is basically going to the menu bar:

```
 session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
```

In fact in yellow is the menu entry I need to execute (menu `Pasar a > Partidas individuales`):

[image]

I've read other post but I can't make it work.

Thanks!!!

Here is the full code I'm using:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim application
Dim connection


If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ZCLPEP01"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/rad[0]").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/rad[0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn[1]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,0]").Text = Cells(4, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,1]").Text = Cells(5, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,2]").Text = Cells(6, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,3]").Text = Cells(7, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,4]").Text = Cells(8, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,5]").Text = Cells(9, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").Text = Cells(10, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = Cells(11, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").caretPosition = 1
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 1
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 3
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 5
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 6
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 7
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,1]").Text = Cells(11, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,2]").Text = Cells(12, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,3]").Text = Cells(13, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,4]").Text = Cells(14, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,5]").Text = Cells(15, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").Text = Cells(16, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = Cells(17, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 9
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 10
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 11
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 12
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 13
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 14
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,1]").Text = Cells(18, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,2]").Text = Cells(19, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,3]").Text = Cells(20, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,4]").Text = Cells(21, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,5]").Text = Cells(22, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").Text = Cells(23, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = Cells(24, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 15
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 16
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 17
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 18
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 19
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,3]").Text = Cells(25, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,4]").Text = Cells(26, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,5]").Text = Cells(27, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").Text = Cells(28, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = Cells(29, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 20
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 21
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 22
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 23
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,4]").Text = Cells(30, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,5]").Text = Cells(31, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").Text = Cells(32, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[2]/menu[0]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,6]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,6]").caretPosition = 18
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[3]/menu[0]/menu[2]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub/1/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 7
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub/1/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "7"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub/1/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickCurrentCell


End Sub
```

Comment: Not really an error that can be solved from our side, you are the only one who can analyze and correct your code so that it corresponds to a permitted user input in the SAP GUI. The line you indicate corresponds to pressing the `F8` key (btn[8]) in a modal dialog (wnd[1]). In the screen where the error occurs, `F8` is not assigned to any function so you can't use it. The menu you show is not assigned the `F8` key.